# Why no redirect after passing "continue URL" to Firebase email/password auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I've passed a URL into Firebase's email/password auth action code settings (see below), however the verification page doesn't redirect back to the website.

Am I missing something, or is the URL only for custom email action handlers?  The docs seemed to suggest that the "continue url" could be used with the built-in verification.

EDIT: This is in the context of a web-only app, not iOS/Android.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(res => {
    sendEmailVerification({url: URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO_AFTER_VERIFICATION});
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL is optional but if you do use it, it must redirect to a custom URL that is a `Deep Link`.

**url**: Sets the link continue/state URL, which has different meanings in different contexts:

- When the link is handled in the web action widgets, this is the deep link in the continueUrl query parameter.
- When the link is handled in the app directly, this is the continueUrl query parameter in the deep link of the Dynamic Link.

Since you are handling it within the app directly, you should be passing it a dynamic link to the relevant page/result. I am unfamiliar with your app's purpose and design philosophy, I can only suggest you read Dynamic Links and make a judgment on your own.

Source:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#type-aliases_1

Comment: Am I correct that deep links are for mobile app purposes?   Mine is exclusively web.  I'm trying to have the "verified" page redirect to the main site, not to a mobile app.

Comment: Dynamic links can be interpreted both on mobile and web - albeit in different ways as mentioned above.

Comment: Additionally, if you are using the default email verification: you can setup a custom URL via 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNiek.png And https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZYVs.png

Comment: If that is also not an option, you can try a standard URL which gets injected in essentially the same as above


`url: "https://mywebsite.com/?confirm_email=true"`